# getting array of ids , but need to get String

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, rest-assured

I,m testing API with rest assured , and trying to get Id's from my created product as a String with the following method below

```
   String productId = response.jsonPath().getString("productPrices.productId");
   String channelId = response.jsonPath().getString("productPrices.channelId");
```

but it's returning me an array

**when I print out those Ids, the following output is being got;**

```
 System.out.println("productId is ===> " +productId);
System.out.println("channelId is ===> " +channelId);
```

**Output is**

```
productId is ===>[jpjeneOM]
channelId is ===>[5bpJKaVE]
```

My issue is , i need to get those Ids as a String only !!!
pls help me to resolve this issue
thanks in advance

**And I have the following payload**

```
{
    "id": "jpjeneOM",
    "name": "NewProductForTest",
    "productTypeId": null,
    "active": true,
    "shortDescription": "API",
    "fullDescription": "API Automation",
    "policy": null,
    "mostPopular": null,
    "longitude": 34.774667,
    "latitude": 32.085814,
    "calendarColor": "blue",
    "address": "Dizengoff Street, Tel Aviv-Yafo",
    "cityId": "nlYxZ6az",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-06T07:49:14.920615",
    "productImages": [
        
    ],
    "productDocuments": [
        
    ],
    "productTypes": null,
    "productWorkingDates": [
        {
            "id": "baQkKROA",
            "productId": "jpjeneOM",
            "fromDate": "2021-05-27",
            "toDate": "2022-12-31",
            "name": "StrickHours",
            "strictHours": true,
            "timeSlots": [
                {
                    "id": "1lkvdZa6",
                    "productWorkingDateId": "baQkKROA",
                    "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
                    "startTime": "09:00:00",
                    "endTime": "20:00:00",
                    "duration": "01:00:00",
                    "quantity": 67,
                    "usedQuantity": 0,
                    "active": true,
                    "deletedAt": null
                }
            ],
            "deletedAt": null,
            "maxUsedTicketsQuantity": 0,
            "errorCode": 0
        }
    ],
    "productRegions": [
        {
            "id": "4lrWZgOd",
            "productId": "jpjeneOM",
            "regionId": "5bpJKaVE",
            "regionName": null
        }
    ],
    "productPrices": [
        {
            "id": "1lon0Aa7",
            "productId": "jpjeneOM",
            "channelId": "5bpJKaVE",
            "fromDate": "2021-08-02T00:00:00",
            "toDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
            "title": "API",
            "remarks": "Test",
            "officialPrice": 34,
            "currencyId": "5bpJKaVE",
            "quantityPerDay": 123,
            "autoConfirm": true,
            "pricePerPerson": false,
            "productPriceTypes": [
                {
                    "id": "xl4WJ7aj",
                    "productPriceId": "1lon0Aa7",
                    "productCustomerTypeId": "ZOw36ZOx",
                    "amount": 12,
                    "currencyId": "5bpJKaVE",
                    "currencySymbol": null,
                    "isOfficial": false,
                    "productCustomerType": null
                }
            ],
            "deletedAt": null
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `productPrices` in example is an array, and you didn't mention which one to choose, the jsonpath syntax is like `productPrices.*.channelId`, so you get arrays. You can choose the first one like `productPrices.0.channelId` or else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response , i did the same as u have suggested 
     **String productId = 
      commonData.response.jsonPath().getString("productPrices.0.productId");
       
String channelId = commonData.response.jsonPath().getString("productPrices.0.channelId");**

and output is empty array ;

productId is ===> []
channelId is ===> []

Comment: Which json path parser are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me an idea  i have figured out with your help  , **productPrices.productId[0],  productPrices.channelId[0]**